# Playframework & Guice without routing

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, routes, playframework-2.0, guice

I would like to know if it's possible to inject dependencies using Guice without having to pass by the routing.
If it is how can I call my `class Test @Inject()...` within my application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to use Guice in Play framework:

**1) Directly instantiate an object based on the binding:**

Add Guice to your Build.scala app dependencies

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0"
)
```

Create a Global class, which extends GlobalSettings, and bind interface to implementation in configure():

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(TestInferface.class).to(TestImpl.class);
        }
    });

}
```

In your Controller or any other class, use the @Inject annotation to get an instance of the interface:

```
@Inject
private Test test;
```

**2) Dependency Injection for Play Controller**

Override GlobalSettings.getControllerInstance to manage controller class instantiation either via Guice:

```
@Override
public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> controllerClass) throws Exception {
    return injector.getInstance(controllerClass);
}
```

How to use the Guice injection?

```
GET     /test1                           @controllers.ApplicationTest1.index()
GET     /test2                           @controllers.ApplicationTest2.index()
```

Route definitions starting with @ will be managed by play.GlobalSettings#getControllerInstance method.